# Partial Fraction Decomposition with complex poles

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

I have a function which I'd like to perform partial fraction decomposition on, to allow easier inverse laplace transform.

$$F(s) = \frac{1}{s(s^2+140s+10^4)}$$

I begin with finding the poles

$$s = 0, s = -70 \pm j \cdot 10\sqrt{51}$$

To which I then try putting $F(s)$ in this form:

$$F(s) = \frac{A}{s} + \frac{B}{s-70+j\cdot 10\sqrt{51}} + \frac{B^*}{s-70-j\cdot 10\sqrt{51}}$$

Because one unknown ($B^*$) is just the complex conjugate of $B$, I only need to find out what $A$, and $B$ is.

$$A = F(0) = 10^{-4}$$

$$B = F(-70+j\cdot10\sqrt{51}) \approx 6.31514\cdot10^9 + j\cdot 6.44274\cdot10^9$$

Where the last step was done in Mathematica.

---

Answer, according to several other people, is supposed to be $B = -70 + j\cdot71.41$, which looks a lot nicer, but I'm not sure HOW they got to that answer.

Comment: This is an error of your calculator: if you tried putting the values into $F$ you would have noticed that the formula you are using is missing something as you are trying to find the value where the function is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the partial fraction expansion of $F(s)$ is

$$F(s)=\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{s-s_0}+\frac{B^*}{s-s_0^*}$$

where $s_0= -70+i10\sqrt{51}$ and $s_0^*=s_0= -70-i10\sqrt{51}$ are the complex-conjugate roots of $s^2+140s+10^4$.

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
A&=\lim_{s\to 0}sF(s)\\\\
&=10^{-4}\\\\
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
B&=\lim_{s\to s_0}(s-s_0)F(s)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{s_0(s_0-s_0^*)}\\\\
&=\frac{-70-i10\sqrt{51}}{i20\sqrt{51}10^4 }\\\\
&=\frac{-51+i7\sqrt{51}}{1020000}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Excellent! One question if you don't mind. I see that $(s_0 - s^*_0) = i20\sqrt{51}$ but how did you convert the factor $1/s_0$ into $(-70-i10\sqrt{51}) / 10^4$?

Comment: We have $$\frac{1}{s_0}=\frac{s_0^*}{|s_0|^2}$$